# Shopify - remove/change quantity of multiple cart items

Tags: shopify

I am trying to figure out how to adjust multiple cart items.

Essentially, we have a custom order page which adds multiple products to the cart. All of the products added have the same unique property.

For example, these two products are added to the cart:

```
Product 1
ID: 1000
Property: CustomProduct2

Product2 
ID: 1001
Property: CustomProduct2
```

The end-user just sees this as one product so I would like a way to remove or adjust the quantities for all products with matching properties with one button.

I know the below wont work but presume if possible, it would be something along the lines of:

```
$(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){
  var property = $(this).attr('data-property');
       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/cart/add.js',
         data: {
           quantity: 0,
           id: *,
           properties: {
             'Property': data-property
           }
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         async:false,

       });
     });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the `/cart/update.js` endpoint. (See [Shopify's official documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/ajax-api/reference/cart#post-cart-update-js)

One point that the documentation omits is that you can use either the variant ID **or the line-item's 'key' value** as the key for the payload. This is important when using line-item properties, as the same variant ID may exist on multiple lines if it has been added multiple times with different line-properties each time.   The key, however, is guaranteed to be unique for every line in the cart.

An example request would therefore be:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/cart/update.js',
     data: {
       updates:{
          "100000:abcdef":0, // Use the line-item key inside the quotes 
          "100001:xyzwnm":0
       }
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     async:false,  // Be warned, async:false has been deprecated in jQuery for a long time and is not recommended for use. It's generally recommended to use callbacks or promises instead

   });
```

One way you might create your `updates` data could be through a simple for loop.  Assuming you have the current contents of the cart saved to a variable named `cart`, that might look like:

```
var updateData = {}
for(var i=0; i < cart.items.length; i++){
  var item = cart.items[i];
  if( /* Check for item that needs to be removed */){
    updateData[item.key] = 0;
  }
}
// Now you can make your AJAX call using this updateData object
```

You could also do this using [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) if you wanted to be fancy:

```
var updateData = cart.items.reduce(function(acc, item){
  if( /* Check for item that we want to remove */){
    acc[item.key] = 0
  }
  return acc;
}, {})
// Now make your AJAX call using the updateData that we created
```

Either way, our final AJAX call will now look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/cart/update.js',
 data: {
   updates: updateData
 },
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(cart){ console.log('Hooray!', cart) },
 error: function(err){ console.error('Booo!', err) }
```

});

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you VERY much, that'll do the trick.

The only thing I'm struggling with is how to use a variable for the line-item keys. I've created a variable called modify which has the right info but's it not taken as a variable.

      data: {
        updates: {
          modify
        }
      },

Comment: Updating to give an example of how you might build your 'updates' object...

Comment: Oh! Re-reading your comment, I think you just have to take out the curly-brackets that are surrounding `modify` - so just `data: { updates: modify }`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you again :) :) :)

Comment: So I tried to create the updatedata with `var quantity = $(this).val();
    
    var keys = $(this).attr('data-keys').split(',');
    var updateData = {};
    for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){
      var item = keys[i];
      updateData[item] = quantity;
    }
    console.log(updateData);`

Comment: his results in `{21343284822075:e65368e4e200a56ef7de8f1ec6b66f7c: "10", 32647120486459:254d0392e43081c624776f9a5be302b1: "10", 32673739145275:4f68d8064868e2c4c0ae0bbb2d7cb9da: "10", 32218184843323:bf5de9d3fac791d9a40f6eeefb97ab74: "10"}` which doesn't work.

Comment: It actually seems to be the lack of space after the first "{"

Comment: Were you able to get this working? From the output you shared above, it looks like it's missing quotation marks around the keys. It should be `{  "21343284822075:e65368e4e200a56ef7de8f1ec6b66f7c": "10" ` ...

Comment: I haven't - just trying to figure out how to convert it to a string and insert the quotes

Comment: Hmm. Are you getting any error responses from Shopify when you try to post the data?

Comment: Makes no sense - creating a string of `{ "32572370812987:1a6763e4289857f88a7a371c6f326091": "0", "32218185203771:34876c86116260b21194b9fb2da1d6a8": "0" }
` doesn't work - no errors but nothing removed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove with fetch

Removing a single item from the cart.

```
function removeItemFromCart (item) {
  fetch('/cart/update.js', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      updates: {
        [item.key]: 0
      }
    })
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then((newCart) => {
      console.log('Updated cart:', newCart)
    })
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded a function to remove an item from the cart based on its variant's ID without jQuery. I hope it helps.

```
  function removeFromCartByVariantID(variantID) {
      // Fetch the current cart data
      fetch('/cart.js')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(cartData => {

              const lineItem = cartData.items.find(item => item.variant_id === parseInt(variantID));

              if (lineItem) {
                  fetch('/cart/update.js', {
                          method: 'POST',
                          credentials: 'same-origin',
                          headers: {
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                          },
                          body: JSON.stringify({
                              updates: {
                                  [lineItem.key]: 0
                              }
                          }),
                      })
                      .then(response => {

                          if (!response.ok) {
                              throw new Error('Request failed with status ' + response.status);
                          }
                          console.log('Successfully removed item from the cart');
                      })
                      .catch(error => {
                          console.error('Error occurred:', error);
                      });
              } else {
                  console.log(`Item with variant ID ${variantID} not found in the cart`);
              }
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.error('Error fetching cart:', error);
          });
  }
```

Usage:

```
removeFromCartByVariantID(39351307173911)
```